# Multiple drop-downs not working in navbar

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a menu and it has multiple dropdown and it is mobile responsive too.
In mobile view only the first dropdown works, any idea is there some issue with js?
Attaching fiddle link for reference

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8L6w3fdu/2/)

```
 <li><a href="">Menu item</a></li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dropdown item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dropdown item 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown second-level"><a href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Dropdown item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dropdown item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript code, you are only selecting the first element with the class of `dropdown`. You need to modify it to select all elements with that class.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown a')].forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show"), this.parentNode.classList.toggle("active"), e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: it worked thanks .. any idea how we can close the first dropdown if user clicks on second and vice versa